# Curl source for random entropy.

Tags: curl, entropy

how do i configure [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) to use /dev/random as the only source of [entropy](/questions/tagged/entropy)?
What i tried is.

```
--with-random=/dev/random.
```

but still, when i do strace curl --help it shows me open of /dev/urandom.

Is there something i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on the TLS backend and library of choice.

As OpenSSL is the most commonly used one, I'll presume you use that. When libcurl is built to use OpenSSL, libcurl itself will attempt to use the random file device that you told it to use at configure time, but I'm pretty sure that modern OpenSSL versions do their own entropy seeding - something that isn't and can't be controlled by the `--with-random` to curl's configure script.

When libcurl is built to use any of the other TLS backends, they all do the random entropy seeding on their own so the random file that libcurl knows about will not be used at all.

Comment: thanks. i configured openssl to use /dev/random in preference and that reflected in curl command executions as well. To check this i logged processes accessing kernel functions get_random_bytes, random_read and urandom_read in char/random.c and found curl process hitting random_read. but, also found the same process first hitting get_random_bytes followed by random_read. is this expected? or is there a better way to check this? i also did strace of curl command and that only pointed to /dev/random opens.